# number of distinct way to evaluate the expression

Tags: combinatorics, mathematical-expressions

find out the number of distinct ways such that

(i + 2*j+k ) % (x + y + 2*z) = 0

where 1 <= i, j, k, x, y, z <= N.

N <=1000

Edit : In case of N=1, the only possible way is i = j = k = x = y = z =1.

Comment: Is this a programming question ? If yes, in which language should this be done ? If not, wrong site to ask (See mathoverflow)

Comment: @Mageek I came across this question on Hackerearth for one of the Challenges.
Language - whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

As, maximum possible value of N is 1000 and for remainder to be 0 numerator must be multiple of denominator.
assume numerator as A and denominator as D.
then, A=kD
where k is an integer.
for finding k we need to find summation of
1000 + [1000/2] + [1000/3] +......+ [1000/999] + [1000/1000]
where [.] is gif.
solve this and that will be the answer.